# Comparison operator for the computed count value in MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I am using Aggregation Pipeline concept and below is the Java code which I used.

```
     DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", 
          new BasicDBObject("field_name", "value"));

     DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", 
          new BasicDBObject("_id" , "")
          .append("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1)));
```

The first pipeline operator "$match" will filter out documents. The second pipeline operator "$group"  will give out the number of documents in the collection (In the above example). Let us say, the third pipeline operator is $project.

```
     List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, group, project);     
     AggregationOutput output = users.aggregate(pipeline);
```

The operation which I want to perform goes like this - I want to use **$gte** operator for the computed **count**  value ( E.g., *if* { count : { $gte : 5 } }  then continue to $project *else* exit).

Could anyone please help me out in solving this problem.

Comment: I don't see the point. All you are doing is obtaining the count of matched documents since the grouping `_id` is null. You it would be more efficient to use the `.count()` modifier on a basic query.

Comment: Yeahh.. I tried .count() before match and if(count>=5) I continued with $match, it worked. count() will scan all documents in collection and give out result. Next I will do $match, it will also scan all documents. (Both count() and $match on same "field_name"). So thought of using count in $group. (If I use $match, next $sum, the number of scanned documents will be less when compared to count() which will scan all documents)

Comment: Please help me to solve another problem. The link is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167849/use-comparison-operators-after-text-search-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two queries: a `count()`, a check for the threshold, then a `find()` with a projection if necessary. You can't terminate the aggregation early based on some condition, as far as I know, so while I think you could construct a pipeline to quasi-fit your demands, really you should do the most natural thing. In the mongo shell since I don't have the Java driver handy to test with:

```
> var t = db.test.count({ "field" : "value" })
> if (t > 5) {
    results = db.test.find({ "field" : "value"}, projection)
}
```

It's hard to give good code for this without knowing more about what your greater objective is.

Comment: What I want to do is - I want to filter out documents based on "field_name" which is done using $match. Next count the number of matched documents. Next, only if this count is >=5, I want to use $avg  in $group. Next use $project and display the output. plzz help me

Comment: What do you want the output to be if count < 5? Empty cursor (no documents)?

Comment: If count <5, I don't want to use $avg in $group operator and just display count is less than 5.

Comment: You can't stop the aggregation pipeline from going through its stages, but you could make it give you no documents as the output in the count < 5 case and then check for that in client code. Seriously though, just do two queries; it's not worth the gymnastics in the aggregation pipeline to do something you can do with two simple queries.

Comment: Yeahh.. I tried .count() before $match and if(count>=5) I continued with $match, $group - $avg, $project it worked. count() will scan all documents in collection and give out result. Next I will do $match, it will also scan all documents. (Both count() and $match on same "field_name" and two times need to scan all documents). So instead of that I thought of using count in $group. (If I use $match, next count: {$sum,1}, the number of scanned documents after $match will be less when compared to count() which will scan all documents)

Comment: Neither should scan all documents because you should use an index on `field_name`. Also, as an alternative to count, you could issue a `find` query like `db.test.find({ "field" : "value" }).limit(5)` and see if you get 5 results. That should do less work than `count()` though I'm not 100% sure since `count()` is internally optimized. One main I'm trying to get across is that you should go with this simple solution until it's actually a performance problem, then examine what the best way to solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59427/discussion-between-user3805045-and-wdberkeley).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use $match again as the third pipeline operator instead, link this: DBObject match2 = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().push("$match").push("count").append("$gte", 5).get();